# Proving continuity at the end points of the extension of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

(Baby Rudin Chapter 4 Exercise 5)

I want to follow up on [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746783/if-f-is-continuous-on-a-closed-set-in-r1-then-is-g-also-continuous-on-th). (Previously, I asked if I needed to even prove that $g$ is continuous on the endpoints of $E$. Here, I want to ask about the actual methodology of proving that $g$ is continuous on the endpoints.)

> Suppose $f$ is a real, continuous function defined on the closed set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^1$. Prove that there exists real, continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$ such that $g(x) = f(x) \forall x \in E$.

My attempt:

> Define $g$ as:
> $g(x) =
>             \begin{cases}
>             f(x) & \text{if $x \in E$} \\
>             f(a_i)+(x-a_i)\frac{f(b_i)-f(a_i)}{b_i-a_i} & \text{if $x \in (a_i, b_i)$} \\
>             f(b_0) & \text{if $x \in (b_0, +\infty)$} \\
>             f(a_0) & \text{if $x \in (-\infty, a_0)$}
>             \end{cases}$
>
> Clearly, $g$ is an extension of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$ and it remains to show that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$. [Then I show that $g$ is continuous on all points of $E^c$]

- Then, to show that $g$ is continuous when $x \in E$, it is clear from the definiton of $g$ that $g$ is continuous if $x$ is an interior point of $E$ and it remains to show that $g$ is continuous if $x=a_i$ or $x=b_i$ for some $i$ (endpoints of $E$)

Now, it suffices prove that $g$ is continuous if $x=a_i$ (the $x=b_i$ case is probably identical). My attempt to prove that $g$ is continuous if $x=a_i$ so far:

> If $x=a_i$ for some $i$, since $g$ is linear in $(a_i, b_i)$ by construction and $a_i
>     \in E$, we have
> \begin{equation*}
>         g(a_i+) = \lim\limits_{u \to a_i+}g(u) = f(a_i) = g(a_i)
>     \end{equation*}

**This is where I got stuck.** Of course, I want to prove that $$g(a_i-)=g(a_i)$$ but I don't know how this can be proven. Unfortunately, I can't adopt the same methodology as I did in showing that $ g(a_i+) =g(a_i)$. **How can I complete this proof?**

Comment: You are repeating the same exact question. You already accepted an answer for your question too.

Comment: @Medo If you look at my previous question closely, you'll see that previously, I asked if I needed to even prove that $g$ is continuous on the endpoints of $E$. Here, I asked about the actual methodology of proving that $g$ is continuous on the endpoints.

Comment: So, say that in the question.

Comment: @Medo Okay, I've edited my question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a_i)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in E\cap(a_i-\delta,a_i]$. If $E\cap(a_i-\delta,a_i)=\varnothing$, then $a_i=b_j$ for some $j$, and proving continuity of $g$ from the left at $b_j$ is like proving continuity from the right at $a_i$, which you know how to do. Otherwise, fix $x_0\in E\cap(a_i-\delta,a_i)$; I claim that $|g(x)-g(a_i)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in(x_0,a_i]$.

This is immediate for $x\in E\cap(x_0,a_i]$. If $x\notin E$, then $x\in(a_j,b_j)\subseteq(x_0,a_i)$ for some $j$, and by construction $g(x)$ lies between $f(a_j)$ and $f(b_j)$. Thus,

$$|g(x)-g(a_i)|<\max\{|f(a_j)-f(a_i)|,|f(b_j)-f(a_i)|\}<\epsilon\;,$$

as claimed.

Comment: I am not sure if it is necessarily the case that $a_i=b_{i-1}$ (as you mention in the second line of your proof). If there are an infinite (countable) number of intervals $(a_i, b_i)$, then it might be that these intervals "bounce around", which would make it impossible to impose the kind of ordering you propose. Do you agree?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: You are correct; that was sloppy on my part. I’ve fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! As far as I understand, you have a slight "abuse of notation" in your proof. You use "$j$" twice in two different contexts and if you were to replace the first occurrence of $j$ with say $k$, then shouldn't one also say $k<i$ for clarity (since your subsequent arguments use this fact)?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: No, that’s not an abuse of notation: *Otherwise* in the next sentence starts a new environment. I never use any order relation between $i$ and any other index. In each part of the argument $j$ is simply some index different from $i$ that happens to have the relevant property.

Comment: Would be it correct to use different indices in the two places, though? And would it be correct to also specify that $k<i$, if one uses $k$ in place of the first occurrence of $j$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: It would be fine to use different indices in the two places, but I don’t see any reason to think that the first $j$ is necessarily less than $i$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: You’re welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it turns out, my question was based on a false premise. If you'll take a closer look at the bullet in my question, you'll see that I implicitly used the fact that $E \subset E^o \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{a_i, b_i\}$-- which is simply not true (I even tried proving it to no avail)! In fact, to prove that $g$ is continuous on $E$, I think one will need to prove that $g$ is continuous on all interior points and all limit points of $E$